# How to permit logged user edit page and if no logged in just display?

Tags: php, html, leaflet

I have a php page,
user can sign up/log in to this page,
after pressing the "map button"
this should load the submap page (leafletjs),
but in two versions:

1. When a user is logged in to my site, he can add marker to this page and that this marker will **stay on** the map
2. When the user is not logged in to my website, he cannot add a marker, the map should be displayed with all markers entered by any user (displayed automaticily)

Few questions:

1. How to display the same page but in 2 version like i said above?
   (I would like to just permit logged in user edit page)
   This is incorrect :

```
if(isset($_SESSION["useruid"]))
{
header("location: ../mapa1.php");
}
else
{
header("location: ../mapa2.php");
}
```

Comment: What's your exact problem here? Using a header would only cause a redirect. Why not hide all edit parts as long as the user is not logged in?

Answer (score 0):

there is some solutions for your problem.

first : you can fix your header function. in header function you have to write a URL not a path.

second: you can use php between your js codes and write a few if,else for handling your problems.

if you send all of your file , i can help you better .

do you have any problem in storing your data ?

(sorry if my English ain't good.)

Answer (score -1):

Do you mean that header location does not work on the browser? you must set the absolute URL

```
header("location: https://YOURDOMAIN.COM/PATH/mapa1.php");
```

Comment: What makes you think that this resolves the problem? Does this help to just display the map for anonymous users?